# Q: how to transform this Gradle command line in a gradle task?

Tags: android, gradle

I have this gradle command line which works perfectly:

```
/gradle app:testalldevicesproductionenv -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=nameofclass
```

I tried to do as this:

```
task testClassAllDevices(type: Exec){
    commandline 'gradle', 'app:testalldevicesproductionenv',
                '-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=nameofclass'
}
```

but it didn't work...

I tried also using args{} but they didn't work either...

How can I transform that command line into a gradle task?

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to execute a Gradle command from Gradle?

Comment: I have some classes with tests to run in multiple devices, and I want to create a task for each class of tests that I have in one of my specific environments, I can only do this by command line now, and I don't want to send a command line every time I don't want to do these tests

Comment: Ah, so you want to execute the same task multiple times with different values of the `android.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class` project property?

Comment: Just an additional question: Is the `testalldevicesproductionenv` task a custom task or generated by a plugin?

Comment: Yes, it is. I usually use to do a battery of tests.

Comment: Why don't you simply create a new task for each of the tests (classes) instead of running gradle multiple times?

Comment: But would these tasks run the test in all my devices? Because I can run each test independently, but I can't do it in parallel.

Comment: To be honest, I either do not understand your problem or what you want to achieve. Could you post the code of your `testalldevicesproductionenv` task?

Comment: I couldn't find it, but is the connectedAndroidTest for only one of my environments

Answer (score 0):

So I understand it as you want to execute the gradle task `app:testalldevicesproductionenv` from within the IDE passing the command line argument
`-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=nameofclass`

You can set command line arguments for gradle through Android Studio settings.
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler
There's a field there for Command-line Options where you can put
`-Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=nameofclass`

Then you can execute the task in Gradle tasks like normal. Of course this will be passed every time you build or anything with gradle but I guess it'll be ignored if it doesn't apply

Comment: This is really interesting, I didn't knew about this at all. But unfortunately it isn't what I'm looking for...